# Unable to edit maven settings.xml

Tags: tomcat, maven, continuous-integration, maven-tomcat-plugin

For tomcat-maven-plugin I need add following block into settings.xml

```
<server>  
    <id>myserver</id>  
    <username>myusername</username>  
    <password>mypassword</password>  
</server>
```

but I'm unable to edit it as it is located somewhere in Amazon ec2.

Can I pass credentials through command line like -Dmaven.tomcat.username="someusername", etc.?

About this plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deploy goal referenced in the docs you supplied says that username and password may be defined on the cmd line with these args:

```
-Dtomcat.username=<yourDeployUser> -Dtomcat.password=<yourDeployPassword>
```

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html.